# Movie where a space bank is robbed

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember a long time ago I watched a movie about some kind of space bank vault with a lot of money in it. All of the crew go to cryosleep except one man who is some kind of security guard.

There were some bad guys who tried to steal the money. One of the ships involved was called *The Endeavour*.

Comment: I appreciate that your first language isn't English, but please do make an effort to check spellings and grammar before pressing the post-button.

Answer (score 5):

This is "[Velocity Trap](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120435/?ref_=kw_li_tt)".

IMDB describes it thusly;

> *In a desolate and treachorous region of space known as the Velocity
>   Run, a heavily armored ship passes every six months. It carries
>   billions of Universal Dollars between the colonies and the Central
>   Bank on Earth. Hard currency has returned due to rampant electronic
>   crime. Now a team of highly trained mercenaries are about to commit
>   the perfect crime in a place where evidence and witnesses have no
>   chance of survival. In this deadly corridor of space, a single man
>   must stop them.*

Ken Olandt plays "Nick Simmons", the Commander of the spaceship **Endeavor.**

There's a trailer below and you can watch the full movie online [here](http://www.veoh.com/watch/v194010838rd6pFME?h1=Velocity%20%20Trap)

Comment: For the record, this film is ***terrible***. May I suggest that instead of watching it, you spend your time more usefully, perhaps having a nice bath or learning some [conversational japanese](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SF39qo4jlNY)?